# Does anybody know how to proxy the index.html in webpack-dev-server or similar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have MVC as my backend. MVC controllers/views have _StartPage.cshtml, _Layout.cshtml (They are combined to form _index.cshtml).

So, I need to use webpack dev server proxy to fetch the index.html from backeend server. Is there any way to do it?

So far this is what I've come up with

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    index: '',
    contentBase: "./",
    port: 8000,
    proxy: [{
        //Only works for api, index.html does not  
        context: ['/index.html', '/api'],
        target: 'http://localhost',
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/TestApp/api' }
    }]
},
```

I'm open to use any other client server beside webpack-dev-server if that solves the problem?

Please note that this will be used only in Development Not in production.

Comment: No, there is no way. You should not use webpack-dev-server on production, only dev.

Comment: @PlayMa256 Yes, this is is for development mode only. The web pack documentation says it is possible to proxy the "root" files

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a different entry for each path. Something like this maybe?

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: './',
  port: 8000
  proxy: {
    '/index.html': {
      target: 'http://localhost/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/': 'TestApp/index.html' },
    },
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://localhost/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/TestApp/api' }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: @ZammyPage sorry the code above is untested and unlikely to work unless you modify it. What was the error you got?

Comment: there was no error and the problem is it is not going proxying to the localhost/TestApp at all. It simply says "404 not found"

Comment: can you include a screenshot of your project folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

How about your project structure?

**The webpack-dev-server must be used in development mode**, after build and deployed, you need to change the api url for production mode.

I'm a front-end and I meet similar problem, I solve it by [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) that could change api in different mode.

My webpack like this:

```
├webpack.common.js
├webpack.dev.js
├webpack.prod.js
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
devServer: { 
    // contentBase: 'dist/', 
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    },
    proxy: {
        '/': {
            target: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx/website/',//url
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure: false,
        }
    }
},
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'SERVICE_URL': JSON.stringify('')
    })
]
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'SERVICE_URL': JSON.stringify('https://xxx.api.com/') //real api
    })
]
```

**fetch/ajax code**

```
console.log(SERVICE_URL)
$.ajax({
    url: SERVICE_URL+'api/%E6%AD%A6%E6%BC%A2%E8%82%BA%E7%82%8E_%E5%8F%B0%E5%95%86_simple.json',

  ...
```

This is my solution, I hope it could give some inspiration.

Comment: please provide code and not image, if the host go down, your response will become useless